# How to store TypeInfo

Tags: c++

```
  class A {}
  A a;
  type_info info = typeid (a); // error type_info is private
```

i want a list `list<type_info>` to store the type of classes. Is there a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is std::type\_info noncopyable? Am I allowed to store it somewhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330835/why-is-stdtype-info-noncopyable-am-i-allowed-to-store-it-somewhere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot instantiate objects of the type_info class directly, because the class has only a private copy constructor. Since the list needs copy constructor...

If you really need it, use std::list< type_info*>.

I don't know why you need this list, but I would think to an alternative design, not involving RTTI, if possible.

Comment: actually my intent is to make a map<typeinfo, typeinfo>. Given a typeinfo instantiating another type.

sample usage :
Get(typeof(PageA)) gives me a StyleA class

Comment: Then you should really use someting like class ids which you create yourself.

Comment: If you know that you're dealing with PageA's at compile time, you should put a typedef inside PageA. Example:

    class PageA {
    public:
        typedef StyleA style_t;
        //....
    };

Then when you want to instantiate the appropriate Style, you just do: "PageA::style_t mystyleinstance;".

Comment: I seem to remember getting typeid for non-polymorphic types just OK (including built-ins). Of course, I don't see how one would use such a map to instantiate anything. I think OP might also look into the factory patterns.

Comment: The "only for polymorphic" part is not true. 'type_info' is generated for all types. No exceptions. The only thing that is specific for polymorphic types is that for polymorphic types 'typeid' will identify *dynamic* type of the object, while for non-polymorphic other types it describes *static* type of the object. "Enabling/disabling RTTI" is a compiler-specific feature, that doesn't exist at the language level. Normally, disabling RTTI will simply make 'typeid' return static type for polymorphic classes.

Answer (score 8):

You can't create copies of 'type_info' objects. However, the result if 'typeid' is an Lvalue and the corresponding 'type_info' objects, once obtained, continue to live till the end of the program. For these reasons, you can safely store *pointers* to 'type_info' objects in your list.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment to Cătălin Pitiș' answer, I understand that your goal is to write a function that returns a different "Style" type for different "Page" types. Does this have to be dynamic? If not, would something like this do what you want?

```
template<class PageT>
struct StyleOf;

template<>
struct StyleOf<PageA>{
    typedef StyleA type;
};

template<>
struct StyleOf<PageB>{
    typedef StyleB type;
};

// etc...

template<class PageT>
typename StyleOf<PageT>::type
GetStyle(const PageT&){
    return StyleOf<PageT>::type();
}
```

Or, with [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html):

```
using boost::mpl::map;
using boost::mpl::pair;

typedef map<
    pair<PageA, StyleA>,
    pair<PageB, StyleB>,
    //etc.
>
PageToStyle;
```

Getting the Style type from the Page type is:

```
boost::mpl::at<PageToStyle, Page>::type;
```