# Why is std::type_info noncopyable? Am I allowed to store it somewhere?

Tags: c++, std, typeid, typeinfo

The `std::type_info` class is non-copyable. This makes it hard to store it in an object for later use. What should I do?

Comment: See Modern C++ Design. Andrei Alexandrescu have implemented similar thing and discussed in the book!

Comment: `typeid(id)` is not a temporary:  it is an object with static storage duration.  the `type_info` object exists until the program terminates.  That's why the `const&` here works.

Comment: Your understanding of temporary life-time extension via reference is wrong. (Coincidentally, though, it works because of what @James said.)

Comment: @GMan, please explain why it's wrong.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: the life-time is only extended if the reference has automatic storage duration (i.e. it's declared and initialised in a function).

Comment: @StackedCrooked: It's only extended in the scope that it's created. Consider (sorry for format): `temp_foo(); /* returns temporary foo, which dies at the end of the expression */ const foo& f = temp_foo(); /* return temporary foo, which would normally die but is extended by f */ struct bar { bar(const foo& g) : f(f) {} const foo& f; }; bar b(temp_foo()); /* okay, but it's extended by g, not f. after this expression, the temporary dies and f refers to nothing */ struct baz { baz() f(temp_foo()) {} const foo& f; }; baz bb; /* same here: f's reference is fine in the constructor, but not after */`

Comment: @GMan: thanks for the clarification. I just noticed that this was actually mentioned in the article I linked to. My bad..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a much better solution in C++11. A new copyable wrapper called std::type_index. You need to include header "typeindex" to use it.

Answer (score 6):

You can store a pointer to a constant `std::type_info` object.

Comment: I didn't know typeid(T) returned a reference to static object. That makes it much easier.

Comment: So why is std::type_info non-copyable? (see question title)

Comment: I changed my accepted answer because today `std::type_index` is the way to go. No hard feelings :)

Comment: @StackedCrooked: No problem, 4 year old solutions are bound to be no longer solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70ky2y6k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  and [IBM online documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/header_typeinfo.htm):

> The `type_info` class describes type information generated within the
>   program by the compiler. Objects of this class effectively store a
>   pointer to a name for the type. The `type_info` class also stores an
>   encoded value suitable for comparing two types for equality or
>   collating order. The encoding rules and collating sequence for types
>   are unspecified and may differ between programs.

Comment: His question isn't about what `type_info` is.

Comment: @GManNickG you are right, but some references miss in the @AlexendreC.'s answer (i.e. Why a pointer to `type_info` will still be valid during the application life?)